# Find difference in files but with a filter

Tags: filter, compare, notepad++, difference

I have two text files that I would like to compare and normally I use Notepad++ with the Compare plugin for this. However, now I would like to compare two files but add a filter to it, so that all differences except those matching a given pattern shows up. For example:

> **Filter**
>
> ^[0-9]{3}
>
> **File1.txt**
>
> 123ABCDEFG 1.0 505 FOO BAR
>   123HIJKLMN 4.3 505 ***BAZ*** FOO
>
> **File2.txt**
>
> 456ABCDEFG 1.0 505 FOO BAR
>   456HIJKLMN 4.3 505 ***QUX*** FOO

As you can see, the compare should exclude the first three digits and only markup the rest (BAZ/QUX).

Preferably, this should be done in a text editor that is nice to work with. At least the output should mark line numbers so that I easily can find it in Notepad++.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check open source [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) tool, it shows you inline differences (`BAZ`/`QUX`), too - [example](http://winmerge.org/about/screenshots/filecmp_inlinediff.png). Any you can still manually edit left and right file although not as comfortably as in N++.

I also have good experience with Perforce's [Visual Merge and Diff Tools](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-visual-merge-and-diff-tools), but these have proprietary license and are free only for small companies. On the other hand, they also support 3-way merge.